# MacPort: global does not accept --set

Tags: python, macports

I am trying to change my default python to python27, I executed `sudo port --set python27` but ended up with following error on my Mac Lion 10.7 `Error: global does not accept --set`. I was trying to see if MacPorts have deprecated the --set command and has introduced a new command instead. But I was unable to find anything related to that on their news website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-set is still there. The issue you have that you are missing a couple of arguments to the command.

It should be `sudo port select --set python python27` The port command takes an action and the one here is select. port select --set then takes as first argument the group it is select for in this case python.